# Making Segments start in a state where nothing is selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UISegmentControl where I'd like if none of the segments are selected when the segment first loads.

Is this possible or do I need to write some custom control?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uncheck the 'selected' checkbox for each segment in the Interface Builder Inspector.

EDIT:

If you are doing it through code, this should happen by default. See the discussion for selectedSegmentIndex -

```
// ignored in momentary mode. returns last segment pressed. default is UISegmentedControlNoSegment until a segment is pressed
// the UIControlEventValueChanged action is invoked when the segment changes via a user event. set to UISegmentedControlNoSegment to turn off selection
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger selectedSegmentIndex;
```

value of UISegmentedControlNoSegment is -1. So no segment will be selected by default

Comment: I'm afraid its all done programmatically. So no XIB avaiable.